# Mongodb Failed to look up SRV record

Tags: php, mongodb

im new using mongodb,im trying to connect using php based on tutorial, im using ubuntu 20, i read mongodb default doesnt have user password and only accept 127.0.0.1. this script runs in same server as mongodb

```
<?php
require("vendor/autoload.php");

$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    'mongodb+srv://127.0.0.1/test?w=majority'
 );
 $db = $client->test;
```

returns :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Failed to parse URI options: Failed to look up SRV record "_mongodb._tcp.127.0.0.1": The specified host is unknown. in /opt/wira/test_mongodb/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php:126
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/wira/test_mongodb/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php(126): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->__construct()
#1 /opt/wira/test_mongodb/test.php(5): MongoDB\Client->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /opt/wira/test_mongodb/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Client.php on line 126
```

Comment: Have you tried to tell the author of the tutorial? It may have an imprecision or could benefit from some additional notes or could it be improved with better trouble-shooting instructions? IMHO the original author should know about it, don't hide your question from that person and make yourself visible. Additionally from the error message it appears to me the syntax is not a well fit for your use-case. Have you double-checked it? Perhaps there is an easy fix. Just an idea.

Comment: And do you have an srv record with that name? It seems recommended in case not (or problems resolving it) to specify all servers/parameter with `mongodb://`  instead. Compare https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1879 , https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/application-randomly-throws-failed-to-look-up-srv-record-mongodb-tcp-somedomain-pri-abcde-mongodb-net-no-such-file-or-directory/148848 and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/tutorial/connecting/#creating-a-client-instance